# How to set tick interval in highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to set `tickInterval` in xAxis it doesn't make any difference in highstock, but tickLength works seamlessly

https://jsfiddle.net/e1on0m6d/

Comment: What is the interval you want? Your tick interval of `1 * 3600 * 1000` is 3.6million milli seconds, which is just one hour. That interval is too dense to be displayed on the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highstock the `ordinal` property for `xAxis` is enabled by default, which causes that some of the  options do not work. You can disable it in this way:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false,
    ...
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e0fsm41j/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal